# Python webbrowser open doesn't open url that has been stored in variable

Tags: python

I just have a simple question. When I do something like

```
 import webbrowser

 webbrowser.open('www.google.com')
```

it works,and opens a page using my default browser
However,when I store the url in a variable, it doesn't open it..doesn't throw up any errors or anything either.. something like:

```
 import webbrowser

 url=raw_input("Enter url")
 webbrowser.open(url)
```

Anyone have any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Comment: What are you typing when you are presented with the prompt?

Comment: works OK here (Win/py27). Are you giving the full address when prompted? (ie "www.google.com", no spaces/quotes)

Comment: I just type www.google.com

Comment: On my computer, it doesn't work either way.  If I include `http://`, it works both ways.

Comment: Are you positive you're not typing a space before www.google.com?

Comment: Yeah I don't throw in any spaces or anything,i just type it as if I'm typing a regular url into a browser

Comment: Okay,tried http prefix,works with that! Thank you! @zondo

Comment: @HassanAli, please accept an answer so this question can show up as answered in the list for future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to include `http://` in the address, i.e., `http://www.google.com`.